# What is the difference between 'form_for @ecard' and 'form_for :ecard'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I implemented a restfull controller with all the correct actions and views. It works currently perfectly with a new_html.erb view that uses a `form_for` containing a structure like:

```
<% form_for @ecard do |f| %>
```

when watching some tutorials i saw that people also use the structure:

```
<% form_for :ecard do |f| %>
```

It sounds logical.. but when i try to use the <% `form_for` :ecard do |f| %> the resulting post goes to a different action then using <% `form_for` @ecard do |f| %>..

-> html result is:

    

 -> html result is:

    

So i am wondering what i am missing, the difference in using :ecard and @ecard are obvious when i look at the generated html but i am still wondering what the reasoning behind this is!

So can anyone please explain what the difference is and what structure i am supposed to be using?? Is it  or