# Difference between :model and @model in form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the difference between using form_for the following way:

```
<% form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :name %>:
   <%= f.text_field :name, :size => 40 %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

and:

```
<% form_for :user, :url => {:action => 'create'} do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :name %>:
   <%= f.text_field :name, :size => 40 %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

Does using @user just automatically use CRUD methods for the URL actions?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582695/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957204/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you give `form_for` a symbol without an instance variable it looks for an instance variable with the same name.

The documentation says:

> For example, if @post is an existing
>   record you want to edit
>
> ```
> <% form_for @post do |f| %>
>   ... 
> <% end %>
> ```
>
> is equivalent to something like:
>
> ```
> <% form_for :post, @post, :url => post_path(@post), :html => { :method => :put, :class => "edit_post", :id => "edit_post_45" } do |f| %>
>   ...
> <% end %>
> ```

Answer (score 8):

If you just give a model instance like `@user` without specifying an action (as in your first example), Rails automatically uses the appropriate CRUD action for your form:

- If `@user` is a new, unsaved `User` object, the form will point to your `create` action.
- If `@user` is an existing `User` loaded from the database, the `update` action will be used instead.

This has the advantage that you can reuse the same form for both your `edit` and `new` views without changing the `:url` parameter for your forms.

As usual, the [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M001604) provide more information.

Comment: Your explanation is much helpful to me than the API doc.. +1