# Rails - Preserve entered login form values when login is incorrect (no session model involved)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, session, authentication

When my app fails to log in due to incorrect email / password combo, it erases the entered fields from the form.

I'd like to keep the entered email while clearing the password field

sessions_controller.rb

```
def create
    #! Do this using email index
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    correct_password = @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password]) unless user.nil?
    if user && correct_password
        log_in user         
        redirect_to user 
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination.'           
        render 'new'
    end             
end

def new
    redirect_to user_path(current_user) if logged_in?
    @user ||= User.new

end
```

For creating new users or records in the database, I know the behavior i want is achieved by using the .save method in the `if` condition, but Logging in iwith sessions is a different story, since you're not creating any new record, nor is there a sessions table.

sessions/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |s| %>
<p>
    <%= s.label :email %>:
    <%= s.text_field :email %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= s.label :password %>:
    <%= s.password_field :password %>
</p>
<p>     
    <%= s.submit "Log In" %>
</p>
<%= link_to 'Create Account', signup_path %>
```

sessions_helper.rb

module SessionsHelper

```
def log_out
    current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token, 
                                                                User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token))
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    self.current_user = nil
end 

def log_in(the_user)
    # Create new token.
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    # Update_attribute bypasses validations.
    # Bypassing validations is necessary here a required password is absent in the inputs
    the_user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = the_user
end

def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end 

def current_user=(the_user)
    @current_user = the_user
end

def current_user
    # Local remember_token variable encrypts token value stored in cookie.
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    # Find user whose remember_token attribute value matches the encrypted result of the token stored in the cookie.
    # Using ||= handles login as well as navigating pages during the session.
    # Doesn't hit database if value is already set - checks value before quering. Good!
    # ||= here uses short-circuit evaluation.
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
end

def current_user? (the_user)
    the_user == current_user
end

def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url if request.get?
end

def redirect_back_or(page)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || page)
    session.delete(:return_to)
end
```

end

Comment: new controller new action could you do this `@user ||= User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)`

Comment: what does the code for your form look like?

Comment: Rajarshi, actually that doesn't work. it gives me undefined method [], and also, downcase gives an error.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use an instance variable in your `form_for` call:

```
<%= form_for @session, url: sessions_path do |f| %>
   //your fields
<% end %>
```

You'll have to set @session in your controller like this:

```
#app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
def new
    @session = Session.new # or however it needs to work
end
```

---

**Instance**

The reason your form isn't re-populating is that you don't have any data to re-populate with. By using an instance variable, the form data is held within that (allowing it to be called again)

You'll probably benefit from reading this: [Difference between :model and @model in form_for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059574/difference-between-model-and-model-in-form-for)

---

**Update**

I still stand by the idea you need to create an instance of the `@session` object

I think I would create a [session model](http://railscasts.com/episodes/119-session-based-model) to handle the `@session` variable:

```
#app/models/session.rb
class Session
  include SessionsHelper

  def initialize(session)
    @session = session
  end

  def new
    @session ||= []
  end

  #replace log_in method
  def create
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    @user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    current_user = @user
  end

  #replace log_out method
  def destroy
    token = User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token)
    current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token, token)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    current_user = nil
  end

end

#app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    correct_password = @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password]) unless @user.nil?
    if @user && correct_password
        Session.create(@user)            
        redirect_to @user 
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination.'           
        render 'new'
    end             
end

def new
    redirect_to user_path(current_user) if logged_in?
    @session ||= Session.new
end
```

Comment: I'm getting errors using that solution, still. I edited my question to include the sessions helper. `@session = Session.new` is not legit, perhaps because there is no sessions model or table? I do not use session table in this.

Comment: Hmm okay - how do you create a session normally? Are you using Authlogic?

Comment: it's manually, via cookie token, bcrypt, and a remember_token attribute (that stores the digest) in the users table.

Comment: Okay so you already have the `user` object from the `users` table. I got confused there - I'll see about updating my answer

Comment: i tried using @user as the variable, but upon failure, it took me to the new_user_path instead of new_session_path. Maybe we can use the @user variable in the form, but at the end of the create method, do `render '/sessions/new'` instead of 'render 'new'`

Comment: the `@user` object in the create method can be a local variable `user` instead of `@user` without any apparent change in behavior as far as i can tell.

Comment: The problem isn't the instance variable; it's how we create & handle it. Because of a lack of model (`Session.new` is not available), I'm thinking about how to handle the data

Comment: so that model should not have a corresponding database table, correct? it's just a model so that the form_for works properly?

Comment: Yep - it's mean to keep the @session variable

Comment: i haven't done the initialize method, or repalced the login methods, but i will come back to this, and if it works, mark it as the right answer. It is a minor feature relative to all the other tasks.

I created a model, and did replaced the rest of the code, but gave me errors.

I appreciate your help so far. Why is it important that I move the log_in log_out methods from the helper to the mode, and rename them?

Comment: It's important because it makes the system cleaner. Helper methods are meant to provide snippets of code you can re-use in your views / controllers. You're handling deep system logic with them, which would be best kept in a model

Comment: I am following the Hartl tutorial, and he uses the log_in function in the create action within the users controller. He has the session_helper included in the application helper, so that the session help methods are available globally. I see your point about keeping deep system logic in a model. I think for now I will have to keep the log_in method as is so I don't run into problems for the tutorial. Thank you for all your help Rich Peck.

Comment: No problem! Let me know what happens - I'm eager to learn how to do this :)